# Indexación páginas google

Tags: seo, google-search-console

Soy nuevo en esto de search console, tengo una web indexada pero tengo 2 dudas:

La primera es:

- Mi web tiene varias entradas, de las cuales una fue publicada el 6 mayo y las otras el 7 de mayo, la urls son https://xxx.com/entrada1 y https://xxx.com/entrada2. Si pongo en google:

  site: https://xxx.com => me sale 60 resultados y una de ellas es laa de entrada1 pero con esta url : https://xxx.com/tag/entrada1

  site: https://www.xxx.com => me sale 10 resultados y una de ellas es laa de entrada1 pero con esta url : https://xxx.com/tag/entrada1

Sin embargo, si pongo:

```
site: https://xxx.com/entrada2 => si me aparece como resultado.
```

La segunda es:

En seach console, inspeccion de urls pongo el dominio tnego estos resultados:

```
-Cobertura: Indexada, no enviada en sitemap, tengo el visto bueno.
-Página de referencia: http://otrodominioquenoeselmio.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

Para el primer problema lo primero es verificar en Search Console que ambas entradas han sido indexadas, si lo están y no lo puedes ver en el SERP (Search Result Page) es decir usando el buscador de Google es normal ya que Google muestra en sus resultados no todo lo que tiene indexado ya que existe un margen de tiempo entre que se indexa y se actualiza el SERP (Lo que puedes ver en google) y Google puede decidir no mostrar una URL asi este indexada,

En muchos casos eso sucede por que Google no logra entender la relevancia de una URL y esto lo podemos controlar con los links internos que tenemos en nuestro sitio

Si mi nueva entrada solo tiene un link a ella esta será menos importante que una pagina que tenga muchos links como lo puede ser el Home o página de inicio.

Por otra parte si tienes dos URLs con una keyword parecida

https://xxx.com/tag/entrada1  -> Página que agrupa muchos artículos relacionados
https://xxx.com/entrada1  -> Página con el contenido del tema

Esto suele ser confuso para Google ya que tienes dos paginas que su URL no es muy clara, en este caso si las paginas de tag no son relevantes es recomendable marcarlas como no indexables asi google puede concentrar su atención en las URLs que si te interesa indexar y rankear que son las entradas.

Por ultimo cualquier cambio que hagas para quitar o agregar URLs no se ve reflejado en un corto periodo de tiempo, normalmente toma a partir de 1 semana que Google actualice su Coverage en search console y un poco mas para ver eso reflejado en el SERP

Comment: gracias por tu sugerencia, ya casi despues de 1 mes que publique el post y sigo estando en las mismas